# s:Add Multiple options in dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am setting minimum and maximum values in two different dropdown. The max value is start when user select minimum value. So i get the value of minimum by jquery and try to add max value using loop. Here is my code

```
var minValue = document.getElementById('min_price_forsale').value;

for( var i=minValue; i>=6000000; i=i+minValue) {     
    $('#max_price_forsale').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
}
```

But this is not working. Is there any suggestion or answer where i am wrong. Thanks

My New Code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#min_price_forsale').change(function () {        
        var minValue = $('#min_price_forsale option:selected').val();        
        for (var i = minValue; i <= 600000; i=i+10000) {
            var optionStr = "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";            
            $('#max_price_forsale').append(optionStr);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: what is the maximum number

Comment: What does `new Option` do ?

Comment: @PSR the maximum number is 6 cror.

Comment: r u adding 6 crore numbers to drop down

Comment: @adeneo new option replace all old options and add new one. may be the code is wrong i don't have any idea how this is happen

Comment: Not 6core i am adding different values but max is 6corer. Like i start from 1,000,00 then 2,000,00 and so on and the difference is increases after different levels

Answer (score 1):

```
var minValue = document.getElementById('min_price_forsale').value;

    for( var i=minValue; i>=your max value; i=i+minValue)      
        $('#max_price_forsale').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
```

Comment: this is not working. it not adding new options, what i do may be the code is wrong or chose an other way to replace new options with old one

Comment: var minValue = document.getElementById('min_price_forsale').value;
 
 for( var i=minValue; i>=6000000; i=i+minValue) {     
        $('#max_price_forsale').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
 }

this is my code and i already write my code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML Code:**

```
<select name="min_price_forsale" id="min_price_forsale">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="max_price_forsale" id="max_price_forsale"></select>
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#min_price_forsale').change(function () {
        var minValue = $('#min_price_forsale option:selected').val();
        $('#max_price_forsale').html('');
        for (var i = minValue; i <= 20; ++i) {
            var optionStr = "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
            $('#max_price_forsale').html($('#max_price_forsale').html() + optionStr);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @AadilAfzal: pleased, to help you :)

Comment: is there a way to replace all new options with old one. because i don't want append

Comment: @AadilAfzal: I am getting confuse. please, tell me where is your old code. Can you share your actual html code. I mean your min select html and max select code. Then, we can do something. By the way I am assuming that you want to clean all old code from maxSelectVal and then you are trying to put new generated option val right..?

Comment: yes you are right. i want to remove all max option and want new generated options

Comment: its working good, but the loop is not working means it just showing one value.